# Logo URL Property Sharepoint SubSite using API REST

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2013, office365-restapi

I need to obtain several properties of all websites of a root site.

I am using:

```
http://xxxxxxx/_api/web/webinfos?$select=ServerRelativeUrl,Title,Description
```

With this url I get Description, Title and ServerRelativeUrl.

```
    ...
    <content type="application/xml">
        <m:properties>
            <d:Description>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eg</d:Description>
            <d:ServerRelativeUrl>/test</d:ServerRelativeUrl>
            <d:Title>Site name</d:Title>
        </m:properties>
    </content>
    ...
    <content type="application/xml">
        <m:properties>
            <d:Description>Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequa</d:Description>
            <d:ServerRelativeUrl>/test2</d:ServerRelativeUrl>
            <d:Title>Second Site name</d:Title>
        </m:properties>
    </content>
    .....
```

But I can't get the url logo property for every website.

**How I could obtain the url logo for all the first level websites from client side?** (see resalted yellow text below)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below REST endpoint it is working at my end, I have tried it out in SP online

```
https://example.com/_api/Web/?$select=Title,Description,SiteLogoUrl,ServerRelativeUrl
```

Comment: Thank you so much !